# Covariance of the product of two random variables with another random variable

Tags: expected-value, covariance, products

Let $X\sim \mathrm{Bin}(p_x,1)$ , $Y\sim \mathrm{Bin}(p_x,1)$ and $V\sim \mathrm{Bin}(p_v,1)$ be three binomial random variables, that are NOT independent from each other. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are sampled from the same binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(p_x,1)$. My objective is to find an expression for the covariance \begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(XY,V)&\end{align}

From https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389662/covariance-of-products-of-dependent-random-variables and Eq. 12 in https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286081 (On the Exact Covariance of Products of Random Variables), I learned that this covariance can be expressed as:
\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(XY,V)&=\operatorname{E}(X)\operatorname{Cov}(Y,V) + \operatorname{E}(Y)\operatorname{Cov}(X,V) + \operatorname{E}[(\Delta_Y)(\Delta_X)(\Delta_V)]&\end{align}

where $\Delta_X = X - \mathbb E[X]$, $\Delta_Y = Y - \mathbb E[Y]$ and $\Delta_Z = Z - \mathbb E[Z]$.
Note that if the three random variables are normally distributed, the third moment disappear (Anderson, 1958). So I do wonder what happen in the case of binomial random variables. Also, keep in mind that this variables can be normalised as to obtain mean 0 and variance 1.

Similarly, I am interested in finding an expression for:

\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(X^2,V)&\end{align}

Anderson, T. W. An Introduction to Multivariate Statistical Analysis. New York: John Wiley and Sons, 1958.

Comment: The very definition of that covariance tells you what expectations you have to calculate. Regardless how you express it before you do the individual calculations. It all depends on the joint distribution of $X,Y,V\,.$ You want binomial variables that are NOT independent? Awaiting your definitions and attempts.

Comment: @KurtG. I am still trying to understand exactly what you meant. I will update my question adding more details about the binomial distributions. In the meantime, I thought that in the case of a binomial random variable,  $\mathrm{Cov}(X^2, V)= \mathrm{Cov}(X, V)$, since X can take values of 0 or 1, and thus $X^2$ would also have values of 0 and 1.

Comment: In other words: $X,Y,Z$ are Bernoulli trials with outcomes $0$ and $1$ and the $p$s are the probabilites of getting $1\,.$ I don't see why using the same success probability for $X$ and $Y$ makes them NOT independent. Please elaborate. Also: your attempts to the calculation of the covariance are still pending.

Comment: @KurtG you are right that X and Y do not need to be dependent, and so we can assume that they are independent. I am still working on the calculation of the covariance. FYI, I want to keep Cov(Y,V) and Cov(X,V) in the expression, so I will rather work out the third moment.

Comment: @KurtG. I still did not figure out a way to solve it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: When I think of this: If $X,Y,V$ are independent then $XY$ and $V$ are independent. Then Cov$(XY,V)$ should be zero.

Comment: Yes, right. It makes sense. However, here we have the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent but not $V$.

Comment: Back to my question three days ago: how do you define two binomials (regardless which $p$) that are not independent? Maybe they exist but I have never seen an example.

Comment: In biology, a good example is the genetic type found in two genes that are physically linked (i.e., on the same chromosome).

Comment: Note that a nucleotide can have only 0 or 1 values (in most cases), reason why it is binomial. The amount of dependence between these variables is related to how far apart they are along the chromosome.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a biologist and need a formal mathematical definition. We know quite well that when $X,Y$ are two uncorrelated standard normals then $X$ and $\rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Y$ are two correlated normals. In the binomial case I don't hink it is that easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150121/discussion-between-caffesospeso-and-kurt-g).